# VBA code to compare columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a VBA code that compare two columns and if it matches it display YES in the third columns else it will display NO.

I have tried.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
    ' compare the selection.
    Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
    ' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
    ' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
    ' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
    '   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
    '
    ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
    ' each cell in CompareRange.
    For Each x In Selection
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: How is your code (seems to be a copy from SO) supposed to write 'YES' or 'NO'?  Why do you want to use VBA rather than a formula?

Comment: We assume the selection is not in  column B?

Comment: Unless you specifically need to use VBA for some reason, this can be achieved by using a very simple formula - `=IF(A1=B1,"YES","NO")`. More information in the `IF` function is available [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    Sub Find_Matches()
Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
    ' compare the selection.
    Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
    ' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
    ' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
    ' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
    '   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
    '
    ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
    ' each cell in CompareRange.
    Dim intRow As Integer
    For Each x In Selection
        intRow = intRow + 1
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then
            Cells(intRow, 2) = "Yes"
            Exit For
            Else
            Cells(intRow, 2) = "No"
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: what happens if they are in the wrong sheet when they run this? And what happens if rows is greater than Integer can handle?

Comment: Obviously, you have to adapt the code for the use. I asume the two columns are in the same sheet, and in the same workbook, if they don´t select workbook and sheet: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Cells(intRow, 2).Value

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant

    Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C5")
    For Each x In Selection
        x.Offset(0, 1) = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(x, CompareRange, 0)), "NO", "YES")
    Next x
End Sub
```

of course, that will write one column to the right of selected cells